# Compare two columns of two different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, analysis

Recently, I switched from matlab to python with pandas. It has been working great, but i am stuck at solving the following problem efficiently. For my analysis, I have to dataframes that look somewhat like this:

```
dfA =
     NUM      In        Date
0   2345    we 1    01/03/16
1   3631    we 1    23/02/16
2   2564    we 1    12/02/16
3   8785    sz 2    01/03/16
4   4767    dt 6    01/03/16
5   3452    dt 7    23/02/16
6   2134    sz 2    01/03/16
7   3465    sz 2    01/03/16
```

and

```
dfB
    In   Count_Num
0   we 1         3
1   sz 2         2
2   dt 6         3
3   dt 7         1
```

What I would like to perform is a an operation that sums all 'Num' for all "In" in dfA and compares it with the "Count_num" in dfB. Afterwards, I would like to add an column to dfB to return if the comparison is True or False. In the example above, the operation should return this:

```
dfB
    In   Count_Num   Check
0   we 1         3   True
1   sz 2         2   False
2   dt 6         1   True 
3   dt 7         1   True
```

My approach:

With value_counts() and pd.DataFrame, I constructed the following dfC from dfA
    dfC =

```
   In_Number       In_Total
0       we 1              4
1       sz 2              3
2       dt 6              1
3       dt 7              1
```

Then I merged it with dfB to check it afterwards if the values are the same by comparing the columns within dfB. In this case, I have to end dropping the columns. Is there a better/faster way to do this? I think there is a way to do this very efficiently with one of pandas great functions. I've tried to look into `lookup` and `map`, but I can not make it work.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) `dfB` and `dfA` with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) by column `In`, then add new column `check` for comparison merged columns and last [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) column `NUM`:

```
print dfA
    NUM    In      Date
0  2345  we 1  01/03/16
1  3631  we 1  23/02/16
2  2564  we 1  12/02/16
3  8785  sz 2  01/03/16
4  4767  dt 6  01/03/16
5  3452  dt 7  23/02/16
6  2134  sz 2  01/03/16
7  3465  sz 2  01/03/16

print dfB
     In  Count_Num
0  we 1          3
1  sz 2          2
2  dt 6          3
3  dt 7          1
```

```
print dfA.groupby('In', as_index=False)['NUM'].count()
     In  NUM
0  dt 6    1
1  dt 7    1
2  sz 2    3
3  we 1    3

df = pd.merge(dfB, dfA.groupby('In', as_index=False)['NUM'].count(), on=['In'])
print df
     In  Count_Num  NUM
0  we 1          3    3
1  sz 2          2    3
2  dt 6          3    1
3  dt 7          1    1

df['check'] = df['NUM'] == df['Count_Num']
df = df.drop('NUM', axis=1)
print df
     In  Count_Num  check
0  we 1          3   True
1  sz 2          2  False
2  dt 6          3  False
3  dt 7          1   True
```

Or you can use [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) without `drop`:

```
df = pd.merge(dfB, dfA.groupby('In', as_index=False)['NUM'].count(), on=['In'])
print df
     In  Count_Num  NUM
0  we 1          3    3
1  sz 2          2    3
2  dt 6          3    1
3  dt 7          1    1

df['NUM'] = df['NUM'] == df['Count_Num'] 
df = df.rename(columns={'NUM':'Check'})
print df
     In  Count_Num  Check
0  we 1          3   True
1  sz 2          2  False
2  dt 6          3  False
3  dt 7          1   True
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael, thanks for your reply! The groupby fuction in the merge function look great. Although, there is something going wrong. Namely, my data is ofcourse larger than the dummy data above. Therefore is occurs sometimes that a value of "In" in dfA is not in "In" in dfB.

in you code, the other values are dropped. Is there a way to prevent this? I thought merging would take care of this.


Edit: I think i fixed it myself with how = 'left' in the pd.merge function. 

Is it possible to  extend my question regarding a next step?

Comment: Done! Thanks again! Btw, the rename approach is very good aswell.